# How do I load a folder containing all of the codes for a program into visual studio basic?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm an intern working on a machine learning program. While I have learned C++, I have no experience actually making programs or loading existing ones.

The code files were shared to me via one folder.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOdUZ.png

The circled folder consists of these files:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qERPg.png

As you can see, a lot of cpp files. There's an hpp file not shown in the image. A compiled exe is also included

I have Visual Studio (2017). My job is to load the project, make a change to a variable, recompile and then use that exe to complete a simple job.

However, when I load the folder into Visual Studio, I am not able to rebuild/compile the code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2rJv.png

How do I load the code so that I can rebuild and compile a new exe?

Comment: Why is there no project already? Or there is, but you dont have access to it and someone has just given you the files. That isn't ideal, since there may be project settings that are important. But ultimately you just want to make a new project then add the new files. If Build does not appear in the Debug menu, you should be able to solve that fairly quickly (sometimes VS needs a reboot, sometimes the project settings are wrong)

Comment: @Tas I'll give that a go. Thanks for the response!